# Is the only way to program an Android App, with Bluetooth, to use Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, app-inventor

It can't be done in the AppInventor, yeah?
Just want to make sure before i go off learning all about Java Programming.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given this link, it sounds like Bluetooth is possible via AppInventor;

https://sites.google.com/site/appinventorresources/home/tutorial-topics/bluetooth

I havent used AppInventor but if you dont have Java knowledge and arent desperate to learn how to program I think it would be worth trying it, especially if you are keen to get your app built sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the implemented BT capability in AppInventor might be quite limited.

some more resources:

http://groups.google.com/group/appinventor/browse_thread/thread/43aa635f1721899b

http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/BTArduinoLED1&usg=AFQjCNGQ4HG_IYNLdauyEYEafnUhEJVJBg

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses, dan m, they helped.

Answer (score 0):

AppInventor isn't capable of doing such things. AppInventor isnt developed anymore so i think it will never be able to do such things aswell.

Answer (score -1):

Android development is not restricted to be done in Eclipse.
You can program in other IDE's or even from command line.